# find duplicates in a sorted list by comparing i with i+1

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have a list sorted in ascending order. I want to find the duplicates in the list by comparing elemnt i with element i+1. I have tried other methods that worked.For example the double loop, but I want to use this method since I am learning python and want to understand why my code is not working.
This is my code:

```
array=[1,1,2,3,3,4,5,6]
def find_duplicates(arr):
  duplicates=[]
  sorted=  sort(arr) #helper function that succesfully sorts a list
  
  for i in range(1, len(sorted)):
      #before=sorted[i-1]
      if i==sorted[i-1]:
          duplicates.append(i) #tried also duplicates.append(sorted[i-1])

  return duplicates #expected: [1,3] 


print(find_duplicates(array)) #actual outcome [1]
```

I am only getting the firts duplicate in appended to my array.
your suggestions will be highly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: `i` is an index of an element in your list.  `sorted[i-1]` is the actual value of an element in your list.  It is meaningless to compare these two values, the only reason that it produced any output at all is that the elements happened to be integers, and one of them happened to match its own index.

Comment: You don't want `i == sorted[i-1]` you want `sorted[i] == sorted[i - 1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of opportunities to fix. First, let's not use `sorted` as a variable name :-)  Next, let's clear up a muddling of an index into `arr` and the value of `arr` at that index.

```py
def find_duplicates(arr):
    ## ---------------------
    ## feel free to call some other sorting function, but let's not set the return
    ## value to a variable called "sorted" as it clobers this built-in function
    ## ---------------------
    arr = sorted(arr)
    ## ---------------------

    duplicates=[]
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        ## ---------------------
        ## Not stricktly needed, but let's define some variables for clarity
        ## ---------------------
        current_value = arr[i]
        prior_value = arr[i - 1]
        ## ---------------------

        if current_value == prior_value:
            duplicates.append(prior_value)

    return duplicates

array=[1,1,2,3,3,4,5,6]
print(find_duplicates(array))
```

This should give us:

```
[1, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing `i` with `sorted[i-1]` instead of comparing the list element which would be `sorted[i]`.

Also, `sorted` is a keyword in python as there is a function with that name - `sorted()` so it would be better to use another variable.